# htaccess rewrite folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess that looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
```

It works fine. /static folder request remain intact, while others execute index.php file.
But now I have to add another rule. When a user navigates to /action/something, then /actions/something.php should be executed. But when I add the following line

```
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ actions/$1.php [QSA]
```

it breaks requests to static folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason, why it should break `static`, unless you wrote the new rule right after `RewriteCond`. What you should do however, rewrite to an absolute URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ /actions/$1.php
```

The `RewriteCond` looks unusual. Unless there is a reason to rewrite static pages without a dot `.`, you should reduce the `RewriteCond` to just

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !static/
```

**Update**:

To prevent the infinite rewrites, you must add another exclusion condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
```

and `action` must be excluded as well

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/actions?/
```

All put together gives

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/actions?/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^action/(.*)$ /actions/$1.php
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Although you probably has a typo as controller line should be RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=$1 [QSA] (note the forward slash in the regular expression). Otherwise it causes infinite redirects, as error log states

Comment: @VladimirHraban No, prefixing a slash prevents the loop, but stops calling the controller too. I updated the answer.